# How do you create and use a .cma file?

Tags: ocaml

I'm creating a .cma file with:

```
ocamlc -o ./_build/myLib.cma -a ./_build/myBtree.cmo
```

But, try as I might, I can't use this file. I keep getting "Error: Unbound module MyLib".

Could someone please post a simple example that uses ocamlc (please no build utility examples) to create a .cma file and then use that .cma file in a bytecode executable.

Completely lost...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating a library by hand, you need to keep in mind that a library has at least two sides:

- an implementation side which is handled by the cm(x)a file for the library
- an interface side which should contain a cmi file for each public module exposed by the library.

For instance, if the library source files consist of

```
lib_src
  |- a.ml
  |- b.ml
  |- c.ml
```

then the compiled interface for a bytecode library could be restricted to just `A` and `B` by not exposing `b.cmi`. Thus, one could have a compiled library with just the following files:

```
lib
  |- a.cmi
  |- c.cmi
  |- lib.cma
```

At this point, compiling a module `User` that depends on the library

```
(* user.ml *)
printf "%d" A.x
```

requires to both link the archive lib.cma, but also indicate the location of the `cmi` files with `-I`:

```
     ocamlc -I lib lib.cma user.ml
```

A second notable point is that a `cma` file is just a set of `cmo` files. It does not implement any kind of namespacing by itself. Thus there is no `Lib` module introduced by `lib.cma`. The namespacing is generally implemented by the build system itself.

Comment: Thanks for the complete example. I was missing the interface files.